# customize Html.Pager genereted url

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pager

I am trying to add pagination to a page with Html.Pager of the MvcPaging, the problem is that the url generated contains the page number in a value named page. 
So I got something like this `/orders?page=1`
I want it to be like this `/orders?pageIndex=1`

here is my code

```
@Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.CurrentPage, Model.TotalPage * Model.PageSize).Options(o => o.DisplayTemplate("_paginationFooter"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PageRouteValueKey` property of `Options` to override the default value (which is "page")

```
@Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.CurrentPage, Model.TotalPage * Model.PageSize).Options(o => o
    .PageRouteValueKey("pageIndex")
    .DisplayTemplate("_paginationFooter")
)
```

For a complete list of all options (and the source code), refer [MvcPaging](https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging).